# Convert Generated by JasperReports XML from Server Side to PDF at Client Side

Tags: java, xml, pdf, jasper-reports, jspdf

I am doing a project where the customer has a very limited bandwidth between branches. When the project is regard of a web based billing system that will produce a bill in pdf format. However because the limited bandwidth, the performance of pdf bill is very slow.

Because the reporting method that I used is `JasperReport`, what I am thinking now is: from the server side will pump out the bill in jasper generated xml file, then the xml will be converted to pdf at client side (in the browser). It is because compressing rate of xml (or text) through http is higher than pdf.

Now the problem is, how to convert the jasper generated xml file into pdf at the client (or browser) side?

Any suggestion?

(found another solution using javascript to geneate pdf ([jspdf](https://code.google.com/p/jspdf/)), however the project seems being stop for a while...)

Answer (score 1):

Good question. I'm not aware of the pure browser based solution, you could use a java applet or a java application started with webstart to execute a java program that does the conversion (with JasperReports jars).

Another idea could be to format the report in HTML and let the user print it with the browser.